# Is it possible filtering (dropping) packets with Winpcap?

Tags: packet, winpcap

I want to filter (drop) incoming and outgoing packets with Winpcap library.

Is it possible filtering packets with Winpcap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: You seem to mean that you want to block incoming or outgoing packets from the hosts's TCP/IP stack using WinPcap. [That it cannot do](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/main.html);

> WinPcap receives and sends the packets independently from the host protocols, like TCP-IP. This means that **it isn't able to block, filter or manipulate the traffic generated by other programs on the same machine**: it simply "sniffs" the packets that transit on the wire. Therefore, it does not provide the appropriate support for applications like traffic shapers, QoS schedulers and personal firewalls.

When it comes to just filtering which traffic you want to capture/listen to, then yes, [the tutorial](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcap__tut5.html) has a page on that.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems the tutorial does not `drop` packets, it filters incoming traffic into sniffer.